# I am having trouble with generating PDF, I want to add Rupee symbol in my PDF and not able to generate it, I am using FPDF for it

Tags: php, pdf

```
$this->Cell(530, 10, "(Figures In ₹)", 0, 0, 'R');
```

it is not working.

Comment: And "it is not working" means what? Do you get an error? Does the script crash? Do you get a document? Do you see some other character? Does the universe implode? _Tell us!_

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML entity: `&#8377;`

It would be good if you tell us what technologies are you using to generate your PDF

Comment: I am using PHP for it

Comment: FPDF to be precise?

Comment: <?php
$this->Cell (530, 10, &#8377, 0, 0, 'R');?>

Comment: $number = 1234.65;
   setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN.UTF-8');
   echo money_format('&#8377;%!n', $number);
Does this work now?

Comment: include UTF-8 for special characters, check the syntax. there is no reason why it shouldnt work